# Many rows in one line (model.matrix equivalent)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with user_id and some values:

```
user_id  |  type  |  amount
---------------------------
user1    |  credit|   15
---------------------------
user1    |  bill  |  100
---------------------------
user1    |  fraud |  10000
----------------------------
user3    |  fraud |   1000000
```

My goal is to have one user_id per line:

```
user_id  | credit  |  bill  |  fraud  |
----------------------------------------
user1    |   15    |   100  |    10000
----------------------------------------
user3    |    0    |    0   |   1000000
```

I'm able to create static statement with CASE, however I would love to have dynamic creation of this part because in some cases I have too many categories.

```
CASE WHEN type='credit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS credit,
CASE WHEN type='fraud' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS fraud,
CASE WHEN type='bill' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS bill
and max() and group by in following select().
```

If you are familiar with R language I'm looking for model.matrix() equivalent.

**EDIT**
I'm looking for a solution in SQL/Redshift. I know how to do it in R, however the amount of information is too big to be handled in R.

Comment: have you tried using reshape() from long to wide format?

Comment: In R? I can't use R because of the amount I'm handling. I want to prepare dataset in database and then offload part of it.

Comment: Check crosstab feature https://gist.github.com/romansklenar/8086496

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Redshift, but thanks for the link.

Comment: I'm confused now. Do you need a solution in R or a solution in SQL (or similar DB language)?
In R the reshape paradigm will work best. use either the reshape function, or the dcast function in package reshape2 (more intuitive). you can also weak the model.matrix alternative to work for you. if this is the direction you'd like to see I can show you how.

Comment: As I understand he need `SQL` solution to work on Redshift. `R` he use only as an example of `model.matrix()` to describe desired behaviour. The bes way to do would be create stored procedure with dynamic sql statement and run `EXECUTE` but it's unsuported on Redshift

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a solution in SQL/Redshift. I know how to do it in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question there is a simple way to expand a column and create dummy variables in SQL, however each column has to be encoded manually:

```
SELECT user_id,
CASE WHEN type='credit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS credit,
CASE WHEN type='fraud' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS fraud,
CASE WHEN type='bill' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS bill
FROM table1
GROUP BY user_id
```

I was convinced that there is no way to construct a dynamic SQL in Redshift so I build entire query in R and later pass it to Redshift:

```
1. Get all possible values from Type column:  

SELECT disctinct(type) from table1;
2. Create a dynamic query in R and execute it in Redshift.
```